# NoClassDefFoundError : spring TransactionalEventListenerFactory

Tags: xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

Below is my applicationContext.xml. tx is part of the xmlns and schemalocation is specified. I do not get build errros but getting runtime exception below.

this is when i try to add

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />`enter code here`
```

Pesudo for pom.xml with spring:tx dependency is also below.

```
////...
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jacksonframework.version>2.7.5</jacksonframework.version>
</properties>
    ...///

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
     <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>


...////
```

Application context:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
         xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- Persistence layer -->
        <context:annotation-config />

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.tax.data" />

        <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
                  <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleds" /> 
           </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

      <!--  <jee:jndi-lookup id="oracleds" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/projectDS"/>    -->

        <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleds" />
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:config/myBatis-config.xml" />
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
            <property name="basePackage" value="com.tax.data.persistence.mapper" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

Exception is :

```
14:20:48,393 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [config/applicationContext.xml]

147 14:20:51,392 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Failed to define class org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalEventListenerFactory in Module "deployment.mex.ear.mex.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListenerFactory (Module "deployment.DataServiceLoad.ear.DataServiceLoad.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory

148     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

149     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

150     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

151     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

152     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)

153     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)

154     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)

155     at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)

156     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)

157     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)

158     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)

159     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)

160     at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.registerTransactionalEventListenerFactory(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:92)

161     at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)

162     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)

163     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)

164     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)

165     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)

166     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)

167     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)

168     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)

169     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)

170     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)

171     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)

172     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)

173     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)

174     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)

175     at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)

176     at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)

177     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)

178     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)

179     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)

180     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)

181     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)

182     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)

183     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)

184     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)

185     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)

186     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)

187     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

188     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

189     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

190     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

191     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

192     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

193     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)

194     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)

195     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)

196     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

197     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

198     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

199     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

200     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

201     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

202 14:20:51,394 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [config/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListenerFactory (Module "deployment.mex.ear.mex.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory

203     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)

204     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)

205     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)

206     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)

207     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)

208     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)

209     at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)

210     at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)

211     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)

212     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)

213     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)

214     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)

215     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)

216     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)

217     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)

218     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)

219     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)

220     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)

221     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

222     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

223     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

224     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

225     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

226     at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

227     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)

228     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)

229     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)

230     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

231     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

232     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

233     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

234     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

235     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

236 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListenerFactory (Module "deployment.mex.ear.mex.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
```

Comment: Do you have spring-tx on your classpath when you are running?

Comment: @ twinklehawk its added to pom.xml

Comment: That adds it to the build path. It does nothing to the runtime classpath.

Comment: @twinklehawk i do see them in the classpath

Comment: How are you adding them to your classpath?

Comment: @ twinklehawk it is available inside my EAR lib folder.

Comment: Do you have spring-context 4.2.4-RELEASE in your lib folder too?

Comment: @twinklehawk  i see spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is confusing, but it is saying `TransactionalEventListenerFactory` cannot be loaded because `EventListenerFactory` cannot be found. `EventListenerFactory` comes from spring-context, and is only available after version 4.2 according to the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory.html). Upgrading your version of spring-context should fix the issue.

Additionally, spring-tx only has an optional dependency on spring-context, so spring-context does not show up as a transitive dependency and tools will not show you the dependency versions mismatch by default (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).